# How to add texture pack to my cube?

Tags: java, 3d, textures, lwjgl

I'm trying to work with [lwjgl](http://www.lwjgl.org/).
I'm drawing 3D cube with this code (ad it's works):

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //glColor3f(1,0,0); // ROUGE
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f( x     , y     , z     );
glVertex3f( x+size, y     , z     );
glVertex3f( x+size, y     , z+size);
glVertex3f( x     , y     , z+size);
    //glColor3f(1,0.5f,0); // ORANGE
glVertex3f( x     , y+size, z     );
glVertex3f( x+size, y+size, z     );
glVertex3f( x+size, y     , z     );
glVertex3f( x     , y     , z     );
    //glColor3f(0,0,1); // BLEU
glVertex3f( x     , y     , z     );
glVertex3f( x     , y     , z+size);
glVertex3f( x     , y+size, z+size);
glVertex3f( x     , y+size, z     );
    //glColor3f(1,1,0); // JAUNE
glVertex3f( x+size, y+size, z     );
glVertex3f( x+size, y+size, z+size);
glVertex3f( x+size, y     , z+size);
glVertex3f( x+size, y     , z     );
    //glColor3f(1,0,1); // ROSE
glVertex3f( x     , y     , z+size);
glVertex3f( x+size, y     , z+size);
glVertex3f( x+size, y+size, z+size);
glVertex3f( x     , y+size, z+size);
    //glColor3f(0,1,0); // ROUGE
glVertex3f( x     , y+size, z+size);
glVertex3f( x+size, y+size, z+size);
glVertex3f( x+size, y+size, z     );
glVertex3f( x     , y+size, z     );
glEnd();
```

I want to put different images on every faces (in a sprite sheet).
This exemple of code is making a face red:

```
glColor3f(1,0,0);
```

How can I put an image on every faces please? ()

---

EDIT: 
I tried [mallard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5056334/mallard)'s example, but I get this result:
[image](http://postimg.org/image/4uhf1wwr3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [slick_util.jar](http://slick.ninjacave.com/slick-util/) to load in textures.

```
Texture texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",
                      ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("hello.png");
```

Before you draw your quad, enable textures and bind the texture.

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
texture.bind();
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
...
```

You will probably also have to set texture coordinates.

```
// top left
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex3f(x, y, z);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, will i have to write "glTexCoord2f(0, 0);" at every "glVertex3f" ?

Comment: No. 0,0 is for the top left of the texture. For the vertex at the top right of the face, you would use 1,0.